# What Rails versions receive security updates upon Rails 7.0's release?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security, versioning

Security support for Rails is described on this page: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/maintenance_policy.html

As I read this, my expectation is that when Rails 7.0 is released, likely in April 2021, the 5.x series of Rails will no longer receive security-related updates and bug fixes.  Is this correct?

More importantly, upon release of Rails 7.0, it seems like only the last minor release of Rails 6.x (currently, 6.1) will receive security updates.  To be explicit about this, when 7.0 is released, I expect that Rails 6.0 (not being the current minor release of the 6.x series) ***will no longer receive security updates***.  Is this expectation correct, or will the 6.0 minor version also receive security updates after a 7.x release?

Any further definitive guidance or clarification on how this works would be helpful, as the linked documentation above is unclear, and this directly impacts the security of customers I support.  (Preemptively, I am not interested in 3rd party security support of older Rails versions.)  Background:  I use gems that are as of yet incompatible with 6.1, but are supported in 6.0.

Comment: You should ask this on the Rails github page or the Rails discourse (https://discuss.rubyonrails.org/)